# React, React Router and Enzyme: spying on history.push() when checkbox changes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using navigation where the checking or unchecking of a checkbox causes a redirect, using `history.push`. I'm attempting to write a test to make sure that this happens, but after scouring the internet for something like this, I can't for the life of me figure it out. Here is my code:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    let checkboxChecked = true;

    if (this.props.location.pathname === '/path2') {
      checkboxChecked = false;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/path1" render={ () => { return (<h1>Test 1</h1>); }} />
          <Route exact path="/path2" render={ () => { return (<h1>Test 2</h1>); }} />
          <Redirect from="" to="/path1" />
        </Switch>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          id='theCheckBox'
          checked = {checkboxChecked}
          onChange={(e) => {
            if (e.target.checked === true) {
              this.props.history.push("/path1");
            } else {
              this.props.history.push("/path2");
            }
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

App.test.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createMemoryHistory } from "history";
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import App from './App';

test('User clicks on checkbox', () => {
  const historyObj = createMemoryHistory();
  historyObj.location.pathname = '/path1';
  const pushSpy = jest.spyOn(historyObj, 'push');

  const wrapper = mount(
    <Router history={historyObj}>
      <App />
    </Router>
  );

  const theCheckBox = wrapper.find('#theCheckBox');

  theCheckBox.simulate('change');

  expect(pushSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/path2');
});
```

Output of `npm start`

```
FAIL  src/App.test.js
× User clicks on checkbox (33ms)

● User clicks on checkbox

  expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

  Expected: "/path2"
  Received: "/path1"

  Number of calls: 1

    20 |   theCheckBox.simulate('change');
    21 |
  > 22 |   expect(pushSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/path2');
       |                   ^
    23 | });

    at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:22:19)
```

Comment: Instead of spying on the `historyObj`, why not just spy on the component's props?

Comment: I'm inexperienced with React. Could you provide an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I figured it out thanks to the following thread on Github: https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/216

It is not enough to call `theCheckBox.simulate('change');` to toggle a checkbox. You also have to pass the new value to it. The correct call is:

`theCheckBox.at(0).simulate('change', { target: { checked: false } });`

With this change, my code above is working as expected.